# Translate label in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to translate this "Height" label without success.

```
<label for="label_height">Height</label><field name="label_height" nolabel="1"/>
```

I have run

```
/usr/bin/odoo -d demo_v10 --i18n-export=es_ES.po --modules=custom_labels --language=es_ES
```

To get translation file, I have translated all term and updated module both in command line -u custom_labels and in the UI, but I still see non-translated term.
Could anyone paste an example on how to translate a label?

Thanks,

Comment: label takes name from field, so field name translation also translates label

Comment: Can you post an example on how to translate the field?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Export Translation:
2. Choose language, in my case Arabic.
3. File format : PO
4. Modules to export (ex: sales, stock, invoicing etc).
5. Click on the Export button and download ar_SY.po file
6. Change msgstr in *.po file.
7. Put that file in your custom module `mymodule/i18/ar_SY.po.
8. Upgrade the module

Hope it will help you.